# I am having trouble with emissions in my materials. How do I remove emissions?

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders, normal-map, emission

I am trying to model a simple room to make my sword model easier to understand (I was getting confused because the reflective material had nothing to reflect), but I cannot figure out how to make my wall material the right colour. I want the walls to be a bright yellow with small bumps on it. I attached a bump map and a normal map to the material. My trouble seems to be with the "emission" value in the "PrincipledBDSM" shader. I cannot get my bright yellow because of it. With the material colour set to yellow and emission set to black, I get a dark yellow. If I change the emission to yellow, I still get a dark yellow. I thought maybe I could change the alpha value of the emission but it seems to ignore the alpha channel. How do I get the object to follow a bump or normal map and let me chose the colour?

here is the file:
https://we.tl/t-46j7Osx6aD

Comment: maybe just put lights in the room and dont use transmission or emission...

Comment: I think you meant to write Principled *BSDF* (Bidirectional Scattering Distribution Function), the abbreviation you've used means something totally different.

Comment: If the emission is set to black on the Principled BSDF then it won't emit any light. Since you're walls aren't supposed to emit light on their own (I assume), you will need to add additional light sources to illuminate the scene. If you don't want to model the surroundings and simply showcase your model, you could also use an HDRI to light the scene.

Comment: @RobertGützkow omg you're right! LOL!

Comment: @HenrikD my room has two lights in it! I don't know how to turn off emission but I don't want it!

Comment: @RobertGützkow I have lights in the room. Setting emission to black just darkens the colour of the wall (I assume because it's emitting black light)

Comment: @LightOfTheNight try increasing the strength of the emission shader of the lamps until it is bright enough

Comment: @LightOfTheNight No, the Principled BSDF doesn't emit any light on its own with the default settings and that includes the emission color set to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0).

Answer (score 2):

try setting the transmission on 0, and emission black

Comment: the image of the normal map is not attached so I cant see how the bump works: it should work tho, the transmission on 1 is changing the color

Comment: This seems to have worked! Although I could have sworn that I tried it before. Can you explain why transmission controls emissions?

Comment: @LightOfTheNight it controls how much light it transmitted. If your walls are transparent, you will see what is behind them, not the light scattering from the inside

Comment: that makes sense, thank you @HenrikD

Comment: could it be that I am hiding the texture somehow?